# Не работают отступы у кнопок в IOS

Tags: html, css

возникла проблемка. В мобильной версии, а точнее на IOS браузераз не работают отступы у кнопок в формах. Сайт - omegakg.tmweb.ru

Скриншот:

[image: скриншот формы]

Форма в модальном окне и на нижней странице. В остальных браузерах хороошо показы. В чём проблема?

> appearance:none не помог.

Сам код с блоком:

```
<div class="contact_rows">
                    <div class="contact_card">
                        <h3><span class="text_bold">Оставьте номер,</span> позвоним в ближайшее время</h3>
                        <div class="card_footer">
                            <form class="contact_form" action="https://google.com" method="get">
                                <input class="contact_form_input contact_form_input--name" required type="text"
                                    placeholder="Ваше имя">
                                <input class="contact_form_input contact_form_input--number" required id="phone"
                                    type="number" placeholder="Ваш телефон">
                                <input class="btn btn--contact_form-button" type="submit" value="Заказать звонок">
                                <div class="checkbox_items">
                                    <div class="checbox_item"><label for="checkbox">
                                            <div id="check" class="check">
                                                <i id="fas" class="fas ri-check-fill"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <input required type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
                                        </label></div>
                                    <div class="checbox_item">
                                        <p> Нажимая на кнопку вы соглашаетесь с условиями <a href="#">Политики
                                                конфиденциальности.</a>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

И CSS:

```
.btn {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 1.9rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #FDC841;
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 25px rgba(253, 200, 65, 0.2) inset, 0px 4px 0px #BD8903;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .btn {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
  }
}
.btn--contact_form-button {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: `display: block;`, полагаю, должен помочь

Comment: Проблема заключалась в использовании input. поменял на button